# Angular select-country does not whant to Install

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi so I want to install  select-country on my angular Project. But every time i'm trying to install it it wound't work.
[That's the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWpDw.png)

Comment: You can try to remove your `node_modules` folder and your `package-lock.json` and then run the install again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your project has Angular version 14, but `select-country` expects version 13. See the docs on GitHub: https://github.com/angular-material-extensions/select-country/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

I would expect that this should not be a problem, so I would try to install it the following way:

```
npm i @angular-material-extensions/select-country --force
```

Answer (score 0):

So thank you so far but I figerd it out. I used the Angular Forms Material / Autocompled and just edited it to fill my needs.